# Best way to process images

Tags: django, flutter

I have a project that I am using django for backend and flutter for the frontend.The project involves uploading many images to the the backend through the mobile app which is the flutter.I want to know what is the best way to process the images like compression,resize e.t.c.Should I do it in the backend after they are uploaded or in the frontend during the time they are uploaded Also as a follow up question,if I decide to do it in the backend how do I go about it.I'm thinking about using signals to process and save the images after the model is created or celery to do same.Also which is best in this case signals or celery?

Answer (score 0):

Using celery is a great idea in my opinion. For image manipulation like cropping, and adding filters do it in your frontend. Image compression and resizing do it in your backend. You can use libraries like Pillow or services like Cloudinary or S3 buckets to achieve this. Again signals and celery both can work well, but Celery might be more suitable for asynchronous image processing tasks.